# x-editable not working with bootstrap 3 in django

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I'm trying to integrate `x-editable`  library in my  web application so that I can create editable elements on my page

I have followed the steps in the [official link](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) of `X-editable`

(Just the `frontEnd` part)

This is my code in my template :

```
{% block extra_stylesheets %}
    <link href="{% static "data_management/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="{% static 'data_management/plugins/DataTables/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css' %}"
  rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="{% static 'data_management/plugins/DataTables/extensions/Responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css' %}"
  rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="{% static 'data_management/plugins/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

{% endblock %}
{% block extra_head_javascript %}
    <script src="{% static "data_management/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" %}"></script>

<script src="{% static 'data_management/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

<script src="{% static 'data_management/plugins/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js' %}"></script>


{% endblock%}

{% block content %}
<table class="table table-stripped">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-center">Visit Identifier</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Visit Date<br/>
                                                <small style="font-weight: normal;">(Click to change the date)
                                                </small>
                                            </th>
 </tr>
                                        {% for course in course.books_set.all %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="text-center">{{ course.name }}</td>
                                                <td class="text-center"><a href="#" id="pub_date" data-type="combodate"
                                                           data-value="1984-05-15" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                                                           data-viewformat="DD/MM/YYYY"
                                                           data-template="D / MMM / YYYY" data-pk="1"
                                                           data-title="Select published Date "
                                                           class="editable editable-click editable-open"
                                                           data-original-title="" title=""
                                                           style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">12/12/2012</a>
                                </td>

</tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

and I have integrated this script in the footer of the template :

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#pub_date').editable();
});
</script>
```

But I don't know why this is not working  ? 
Any help is really appreciated

**EDIT**

I have noticed that maybe the problem is due to the id is duplicated because I have a `for loop` and the id must be unique !

How can I avoid this ?

Is there a way to create a class and call all the elements by class? I'm not really good on `css` and `html` .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by :

1. change the version of `x-editable` to 1.5  adapted to `bootstrap 3`
2. remove `id="pub_date"` and switch it by `data-name="pub_date"`
3. and put this script :

   ```
    <script>

     $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';

   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('[data-name=pub_date]').editable();
   });
   </script>
   ```

hope that it helps someone else.